# Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

How can I prove that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}}{n^2}=\frac{11}{4}\zeta(3)+\zeta(2)+4\log(2)-4$$

I think [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq/469785) can help me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You like Mathematica, don't you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

UPDATED: In this [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604316/sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn2-2n-zeta3-frac12-log2-zeta2/605602#605602) I proved that (if $\,\operatorname{Li}$ is the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)) :
$$S(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}\, x^n=\zeta(3)+\frac{\ln(1-x)^2\ln(x)}{2}+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)$$

Taking the limit as $x\to 1$ and $x\to -1$ we get :
$$S(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}=2\,\zeta(3),\quad S(-1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\;H_n}{n^2}=-\frac 58\zeta(3)$$

To obtain the limit for $S(1)$ use $\,\operatorname{Li}_n(\epsilon)\sim\epsilon\,$ as $|\epsilon|\to 0\,$ and $\,\operatorname{Li}_n(1)=\zeta(n)\,$.

For $S(-1)$ the method is rather long $(*)$ so let's come back to the integral expression from my previous answer applied to $x=-1$ (using $\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)=-\frac34\zeta(3)$ from $(*)$) :
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}(-1)^n&=\int_0^{-1} \frac {\ln(1-x)^2}{2\,x}dx+\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac {\ln(1+x)^2}{2\,x}dx-\frac 34\zeta(3)\\
\end{align}

Integrals like $\;\displaystyle a_k:=\int_0^1 \frac {\ln(1+x)^k}xdx\,$ were studied by Nielsen and [Ramanujan](http://books.google.de/books?id=RkJecRADwNIC&pg=PA73) who found that $\displaystyle a_1=\frac{\zeta(2)}2,\;a_2=\frac{\zeta(3)}4$ so that $\;\displaystyle S(-1)=\frac 12\frac{\zeta(3)}4-\frac{\zeta(3)}4=-\frac 58\zeta(3)$

We conclude that : 
$$S(1)+S(-1)=2\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2m}}{(2m)^2}=2\,\zeta(3)-\frac 58\zeta(3)=\frac {11}8\zeta(3)$$
and 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n+1}}{n^2}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}+\frac 1{2n+1}}{n^2}\\
&=\frac {11}4\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2(2n+1)}\\
&=\frac {11}4\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2}-\frac 4{2n}+\frac 4{2n+1}\\
&=\frac {11}4\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2}+4\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\\
&=\frac {11}4\zeta(3)+\zeta(2)+4(\ln(1+1)-1)\\
\end{align}

---

Concerning the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+k}}{n^2}\;$ we simply add individual terms (as $+\frac 1{2n+1}$ previousy) and the same method still works : expand the remaining terms in partial fractions and evaluate the series.

For $k=5$ (using computer algebra of course) I got the previously evaluated $\; \displaystyle\frac {11}4\zeta(3)+$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n^2}\left(\frac 1{2n+1}+\frac 1{2n+2}+\frac 1{2n+3}+\frac 1{2n+4}+\frac 1{2n+5}\right)=\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{137}{60n^2}-\frac{5269}{1800\,n} + \frac 1{2(n + 1)} + \frac 1{8(n + 2)} + \frac 4{2n + 1} + \frac 4{9(
2n + 3)} + \frac 4{25(2n + 5)}=\\
\frac{1036}{225}\ln(2) + \frac{137}{60}\zeta(2) - \frac{298373}{54000}
$$

For $k=4$ the additional terms are $\displaystyle +\frac{40}9\ln(2) + \frac{25}{12}\zeta(2) - \frac{2281}{432}$ that you may compare with your result.

All results obtained for $k>0$ could be written as $\; \displaystyle R(k)=\frac{11}4\zeta(3)+p_k\,\zeta(2)+q_k\,\ln(2)+r_k\;$ for every $k>0$ with $p_k,q_k,r_k\in\mathbb{Q}\,$.

---

$(*)$ Alternative method to evaluate $S(-1)$ (complicated, left for the record only) :

- $\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)=-\frac34\zeta(3)$ from the [second formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions) $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_n(-1)=-\left(1-\frac 1{2^{n-1}}\right)\zeta(n)$
- the inversion formula $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_3(z)=\operatorname{Li}_3(1/z)+2\zeta(2)\ln(z)-\frac{i\pi}2\ln(z)^2-\frac 16\ln(z)^3\;$ for $z>1$ applied to $z=2$.
- the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values) $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_3(1/2)=\frac 78\zeta(3)-\frac{\zeta(2)\ln(2)}2+\frac 16\ln(2)^3\,$ to conclude that $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_3(2)=\frac 78\zeta(3)-\frac{i\pi}2\ln(2)^2+\frac{\pi^2}4\ln(2)$.
- the same way obtain $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_2(2)=-\frac{\pi^2}4-\frac12(\ln(2)+i\pi)^2+\frac 12\ln(2)^2\;$ from $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=-\operatorname{Li}_2(1/z)+2\zeta(2)-i\pi\ln(z)-\frac 12\ln(z)^2\;$ and the formula for $\operatorname{Li}_2(1/2)$.

Comment: Thanks very much. Why $S(1)-S(-1)=2\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2m}}{(2m)^2}$?

Comment: If we let $n=2m$ then $S(1)-S(-1)=0$.

Comment: You are right @ALGEAN I had two signs wrong since the odd terms had to cancel (corrected).

Comment: +1.  For a different evaluation of $S(-1)$ that relies solely on manipulation of the summation, see robjohn's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/499716/2370).

Comment: @MikeSpivey: really neat trick from robjohn indeed (and an impressive thread!). Many thanks to share Mike,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: You're welcome.  It was one of those questions where the quality of the answers far exceeded my expectations!

Comment: @MikeSpivey: here too simpler answers could be given to evaluate directly $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n}}{n^2}$ or possibly $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{2n+1}}{n^2}$ (but these things take much time so...). You were indeed lucky !

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{2n + 1} \over n^{2}}} & =
4\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{2n + 1} \over \pars{2n}^{2}} =
4\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{n + 1} \over n^{2}}\,
{1 + \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2} =
2\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over \pars{n - 1}^{2}}\,
\bracks{1 - \pars{-1}^{n}}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{2n + 1} \over n^{2}}} & =
2\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}H_{n}\bracks{1 - \pars{-1}^{n}}\
\overbrace{\pars{-\int_{0}^{1}y^{n - 2}\,\,\ln\pars{y}\,\dd y}}
^{\ds{1 \over \pars{n - 1}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
-2\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}
\bracks{H_{n}\,y^{n} - H_{n}\,\pars{-y}^{n}}\,{\dd y \over y^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
-2\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y}\bracks{-2y - {\ln\pars{1 - y} \over 1 - y} +
{\ln\pars{1 + y} \over 1 + y}}\,\,{\dd y \over y^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y}\bracks{{\ln\pars{1 - y} \over \pars{1 - y}y^{2}} -
{\ln\pars{1 + y} \over \pars{1 + y}y^{2}} + {2 \over y}}\,\dd y\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

However,
\begin{align}
{\ln\pars{1 - y} \over \pars{1 - y}y^{2}} & =
{\ln\pars{1 - y} \over y} + {\ln\pars{1 - y} \over y^{2}} +
{\ln\pars{1 - y} \over 1 - y}
\\[5mm]
{\ln\pars{1 + y} \over \pars{1 + y}y^{2}} & =
-\,{\ln\pars{1 + y} \over y} + {\ln\pars{1 + y} \over y^{2}} +
{\ln\pars{1 + y} \over 1 + y}
\end{align}

---

With these expressions, $\ds{\pars{2}}$ is reduced to:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{2n + 1} \over n^{2}}}\ &\ =\
\overbrace{2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y^{2}} \over y}\,\dd y}
^{\ds{\,\mathcal{I}_{1}}}\ +\ \overbrace{%
4\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y}\bracks{%
{1 \over y} - {\,\mathrm{arctanh}\pars{y} \over y^{2}}}\,\dd y}
^{\ds{\,\mathcal{I}_{2}}}
\\[3mm] &\ +\ \underbrace{%
2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y}
_{\ds{\,\mathcal{I}_{3}}}\ -\ \underbrace{
2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 + y} \over 1 + y}\,\dd y}
_{\ds{\,\mathcal{I}_{4}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\,\mathcal{I}_{1} + \,\mathcal{I}_{2} + \,\mathcal{I}_{3} -\,\mathcal{I}_{4}
\tag{3}
\end{align}

---

We'll evaluate the integrals $\ds{\,\mathcal{I}_{k}\,,\ k = 1,2,3,4}$:

1. $\ds{\large\,\mathcal{I}_{1} :\ ?}$.
   \begin{align}
   \,\mathcal{I}_{1} & =
   2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y^{2}} \over y}\,\dd y\
   \stackrel{y^{2}\ \mapsto\ y}{=}\
   \half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y} \over y}\,\dd y\tag{4.a}
   \\[5mm] & =
   -\,\half\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y}\Li{2}'\pars{y}\,\dd y =
   \half\int_{0}^{1}{\Li{2}\pars{y} \over y}\,\dd y =
   \half\int_{0}^{1}\Li{3}'\pars{y}\,\dd y
   \\[5mm] & =
   \half\Li{3}\pars{1} =
   \fbox{$\ds{\ \half\,\zeta\pars{3}\ }$} = \,\mathcal{I}_{1}\tag{4.b}
   \end{align}

   ---
2. $\ds{\large\,\mathcal{I}_{2} :\ ?}$. With the $\ds{\,\mathrm{arctanh}\pars{y}}$ expansion in powers of $\ds{y}$:
   \begin{align}
   \,\mathcal{I}_{2} & =
   4\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y}\bracks{%
   {1 \over y} - {\,\mathrm{arctanh}\pars{y} \over y^{2}}}\,\dd y =
   4\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y}\bracks{%
   {1 \over y} -
   {1 \over y^{2}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{y^{2n + 1} \over 2n + 1}}\,\dd y
   \\[5mm] & =
   -4\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2n + 3}\ \overbrace{%
   \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{y}\,y^{2n + 1}\,\,\dd y}
   ^{\ds{-\,{1 \over 4\pars{n + 1}^{2}}}}\ =\
   \left.-\,\half\,\partiald{}{\mu}
   \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + \mu}\pars{n + 3/2}}
   \right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 1}
   \\[5mm] & =
   \left.\vphantom{\huge A^{A}}-\,\half\,\partiald{}{\mu}
   \bracks{\Psi\pars{\mu} - \Psi\pars{3/2} \over \mu - 3/2}
   \right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 1}\qquad\qquad\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
   \\[5mm] & =
   \fbox{$\ds{\ 4\ln\pars{2} - 4 + {\pi^{2} \over 6}\ }$} =
   \,\mathcal{I}_{2}\tag{5}
   \end{align}

   ---
3. $\ds{\large\,\mathcal{I}_{3} :\ ?}$.
   \begin{align}
   \,\mathcal{I}_{3} & =
   2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 - y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y\
   \stackrel{y\ \mapsto\ \pars{1 - y}}{=}\,\,\,
   2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - y}\ln\pars{y} \over y}\,\dd y
   \\[5mm] & =
   4\,\mathcal{I}_{1}\qquad\qquad
   \pars{~\mbox{see}\ \pars{\mbox{4.a}}\ \mbox{and}\ \pars{\mbox{4.b}}~}
   \\[5mm] & =
   \fbox{$\ds{\  2\zeta\pars{3}\ }$} = \,\mathcal{I}_{3}\tag{6}
   \end{align}

   ---
4. $\ds{\large\,\mathcal{I}_{4} :\ ?}$.
   \begin{align}
   \,\mathcal{I}_{4} & =
   2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{y}\ln\pars{1 + y} \over 1 + y}\,\dd y =
   -\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + y} \over y}\,\dd y
   \\[5mm] & \stackrel{\pars{1 + y}\ \mapsto\ y}{=}\
   -\int_{1}^{2}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over y - 1}\,\dd y\
   \stackrel{y\ \mapsto\ 1/y}{=}\
   -\int_{1}^{1/2}{\ln^{2}\pars{1/y} \over 1/y - 1}\,\pars{\dd y \over -y^{2}}
   \\[5mm] & =
   -\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over y\pars{1 - y}}\,\dd y =
   -\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over y}\,\dd y -
   \int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y
   \\[5mm] & =
   -\,{1 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + \ln^{3}\pars{2} -
   \int_{1/2}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - y}\,2\ln\pars{y}\,{1 \over y}\,\dd y
   \\[5mm] & =
   {2 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + 2\int_{1/2}^{1}\Li{2}'\pars{y}\ln\pars{y}\,\dd y
   \\[5mm] & =
   {2 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + 2\ln\pars{2}\Li{2}\pars{\half} -2\int_{1/2}^{1}\overbrace{{\Li{2}\pars{y}\over y}}^{\ds{\Li{3}'\pars{y}}}
   \,\dd y
   \\[5mm] & =
   {2 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + 2\ln\pars{2}\Li{2}\pars{\half} -2\Li{3}\pars{1} + 2\Li{3}\pars{\half}
   \end{align}
   The $\ds{\Li{s}}$ values involved in this expression are well known:
   $\ds{\Li{2}\pars{\half} = {\pi^{2} \over 12} - \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}}$,
   $\ds{\Li{3}\pars{1} = \zeta\pars{3}}$ and $\ds{\Li{3}\pars{\half} =
   {7 \over 8}\,\zeta\pars{3} + {1 \over 6}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} -
   {\pi^{2} \over 12}\,\ln\pars{2}}$ such that
   \begin{equation}
   \,\mathcal{I}_{4} = \fbox{$\ds{\ -\,{1 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}\ }$}\tag{7}
   \end{equation}

   ---

   With $\ds{\pars{3}}$$,\ds{\pars{\mbox{4.b}}}$, $\ds{\pars{5}}$, $\ds{\pars{6}}$ and $\ds{\pars{7}}$, we find the $\ds{\underline{final\ result}}$
   $$
   \color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{2n + 1} \over n^{2}}} =
   \color{#f00}{{11 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3} + \zeta\pars{2} + 4\ln\pars{2} - 4}
   \approx 3.7232\,,\qquad {\pi^{2} \over 6} = \zeta\pars{2}
   $$

Answer (score 3):

Using the following nice rule: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}\left(\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\right)$$

We get
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}}{n^2}=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}}{{(2n)}^2}=4\left(\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n+1}}{n^2}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n+1}}{n^2}\right)\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2(n+1)}\\
&=2\left(2\zeta(3)\right)+2\left(-\frac58\zeta(3)\right)+2\left(\zeta(2)-1\right)+2\left(2\ln2-\frac12\zeta(2)-1\right)\\
&=\frac{11}4\zeta(3)+\zeta(2)+4\ln2-4
\end{align}

Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^2}$ was obtained from using the generating function where we set $x=-1$ :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\frac{H_n}{n^2}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Different approach:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}}{n^2}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2(2n+1)}$$

where
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{n^2}=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^2}$$
$$=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2n}\left(-\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln(1-x)dx\right)$$

$$=-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n}$$

$$=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx$$

$$=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx+2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$$

$$=2(2\zeta(3))+2(-\frac58\zeta(3))=\frac{11}{4}\zeta(3)$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2(2n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^1 x^{2n}dx$$
$$=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n^2}=\int_0^1\text{Li}_2(x^2)dx$$

$$=x\text{Li}_2(x^2)|_0^1+2\int_0^1\ln(1-x^2)dx$$

$$=\zeta(2)+2(x-1)\ln(1-x^2)|_0^1-4\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x}dx$$

$$=\zeta(2)-4(1-\ln(2))$$