# Canonical reference for algebraic theory of polylogs?

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, polylogarithm, differential-field

I've noticed that there are lots of similar-looking (at least to my untrained eye) questions on Math Stackexchange involving polylogarithms, all equally delicious, in which the OP asks about how to calculate some integral involving a complicated product of logs/polylogs/algebraic functions, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937912/closed-form-of-int-01-frac-operatornameli-2-left-x-right-sqrt1-x2), [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921641/closed-form-for-large-int-01-frac-ln1-x-ln1x-ln12x12xdx), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243/remarkable-logarithmic-integral-int-01-frac-log2-1-x-log2-x-log31x), or an infinite series involving harmonic numbers, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612181/triple-euler-sum-result-sum-k-geq-1-frach-k2h-k-k2-zeta2-zeta3) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609056/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frach-2n1n2). There are a lot of similarities between their answers as well: they usually end up being a linear combination of rational multiples of powers of pi, logarithms of algebraic numbers, integer zeta-function values, and polylogarithm evaluations.

Although I have very little experience/knowledge regarding logarithms, these similarities suggest that there might be a more general *algebraic* approach to calculating these types of sums/integrals/polylog identities. The extremely general nature of the top-voted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921641/closed-form-for-large-int-01-frac-ln1-x-ln1x-ln12x12xdx) is even more suggestive of this possibility - however, although it demonstrates the existence of a general expression in terms of multiple polylogarithm values, it doesn't discuss ways of *simplifying* these values (which, ideally, would also be part of an algebraic theory of polylogs).

- What kind of research exists about the *algebraic* properties of special functions consisting of, say, products of polylogs and algebraic functions, or polylogs and rational functions, and their derivatives/antiderivatives? Does differential field theory have anything interesting to say about this, for instance?
- Is there a canonical reference book or paper which discusses this topic in depth, from an algebraic perspective?
- At the bottom of [Wolfram's page on polylogs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html), they refer to an "amazing identity" involving a special value of $\text{Li}_{17}(\alpha_1^{-17})$, where $\alpha_1$ is defined as the root of a polynomial. Are there any general references exploring the *general* problem of finding linear dependences between polylog values at algebraic arguments? Again, does differential field theory shed any light here?