# How to get a closed form for the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{H_{2n}}{2n^2}}$?

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

Is there any technique to get a closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{H_{2n}}{2n^2}}$?

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this was contained in [Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n+1}}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609056/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frach-2n1n2?noredirect=1&lq=1), its just $\frac{11}{8}\zeta(3)$.