# Integral, definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

How can we prove

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \cdot \ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=-\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}?
$$

This has been one of the integrals that came out of an integral from another post on here, but no solution to it.

I am not sure how to use a taylor series expansion for the $\ln(1+x)\cdot(x+1)^{-1}$ term, thus I can not simple reduce this integral to the form
$$
\int_0^1 x^n \ln x dx
$$
I think if I can get the integral in this form, I will be able to recover the zeta function series which is given by
$$
\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}.
$$
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to write down that the power series for $\frac{{\rm ln}(1+x)}{1+x}$ is the Cauchy product of the power series for ${\rm ln}(1+x)$ and the power series of $\frac1{1+x}$?

Comment: @Etienne No what is that?  I am not sure how to perform the convolution since it is a discrete sum.  For continuous sums (integrals) I don't mind inverse transforms

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: @Etienne Okay yes I did, I obtain the sum of the cauchy product 
$\ln(x+1)\cdot \frac{1}{x}$ where I used the convolution on the $1/(1+x)$ term.  THanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Etienne There is a problem when I am doing the convolution because when I do the integral I no longer have a zeta function result, do you know why?  $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{k+1}}{k+1} \cdot (-1)^{n-k} x^{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{k}.$$  If I integrate this result I do not get a zeta function

Comment: @Jeff. I think that the rhs in your last comment to Etienne is wrong.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I fixed it, typo thanks.

Comment: My name is Integral. Definite Integral. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played around with this using parts because it looks like an integral that involves polylogs.  Many of these can be done with parts or multiple use of parts.

$$\int\frac{log(x)log(1+x)}{1+x}dx$$

Let $$u=x+1$$

$$\int\frac{log(u-1)log(u)}{u}du=\int\frac{log(u)}{u}\left(log(u)+log(1-1/u)\right)du$$

$$=\frac{log^{3}(u)}{3}+\int\frac{log(u)log(1-1/u)}{u}du$$

Now, use parts on this last integral:

$u=log(u), \;\ dv=\frac{log(1-1/u)}{u}, \;\ du=\frac{1}{u}du, \;\ v=Li_{2}(1/u)$

(as a note, $\int\frac{log(1-1/u)}{u}du=Li_{2}(1/u)$ is a rather famous integral related to the dilog).

$$\int\frac{log(u)log(1-1/u)}{u}du=log(u)Li_{2}(1/u)-\int\frac{Li_{2}(1/u)}{u}du$$

Also, note this last integral is simply $$-Li_{3}(1/u)$$

Now, back sub $u=x+1$, and put it altogether using the integration limits 0 to 1.

Hence, we arrive at:

$$ \left|1/3log^{3}(x+1)+log(x+1)Li_{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)+Li_{3}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\right|_{0}^{1}$$

$$=1/3log^{3}(2)+log(2)Li_{2}(1/2)+Li_{3}(1/2)-Li_{3}(1).........(1)$$

Note the identities:

$$Li_{2}(1/2)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}-1/2log^{2}(2)$$

$$Li_{3}(1/2)=7/8\zeta(3)+1/6log^{3}(2)-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}log(2)$$

sum up (1):

$$1/3log^{3}(2)+log(2)\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}-1/2log^{2}(2)\right)+\left(7/8\zeta(3)+1/6log^{3}(2)-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}log(2)\right)-\zeta(3)$$

$$=\frac{-\zeta(3)}{8}$$

Answer (score 4):

I think this ties together the aforementioned ideas quite nicely:

Step 1: Integrate by parts. Let $u=\log{x}$ and $dv=\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}$. We obtain $v=\frac{1}{2} [\log(1+x)]^2$. Being somewhat careful with the limits, we see that the integral itself is equal to
$$ -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{[\log(1+x)]^2}{x}\,dx $$

Step 2: Expand $\log(1+x)$ and $\log(1+x)/x$ into their Taylor series and combine.
$$ -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j+1} \frac{x^j}{j}\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{x^i}{i+1}\right)\,dx = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+j+1}}{j(i+1)(i+j+1)} $$

Step 3: There are a few ways to go here, but I like $k=i+j+1$ followed by a partial fraction decomposition. Then,
$$ -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{j(k-j)} = -\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} H_{k-1} $$

Step 4: ??? It is not clear to me why this quantity is the desired one, but prior responses seem to indicate as such. Anybody else with thoughts?

[edit] I had an $H_k$ that should have been an $H_{k-1}$. Fixed now.

[edit 2] A more direct approach from the generating function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generating_functions) of the harmonic sequence:
Since $-\sum_{k=1}^\infty H_k (-x)^k = \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}$, we have
$$ -\int_0^1 \log(x) \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k H_k x^k\,dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2} H_k $$
Definitely simpler, but requires a priori knowledge of the generating function.

Comment: Very nice and clear to follow.  Thanks a lot @Jason

Answer (score 1):

The integral can have the form

> $$ I = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\,H_{k}}{k^2}-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(3), $$

$H_k$ are the [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). Try to work out above sum. See a [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457371/alternating-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1kk3h-k).

Comment: from that result, how are you getting $-\zeta(3)/8$?  I will try and work this sum out now...What did you do though to get the harmonic number sum?   How do you manipulate the integrand to get that result.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff: Mathematica can give you a closed form for this sum.

Comment: how did you find that form for the Integrand though?  I see mathematica can evaluate the harmonic sum, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A handy thing to note for evaluating $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{(n+1)^{2}}$$ is to use $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{(n+1)^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{n^{2}}-\zeta(3)$$............[1]

The first sum on the right can be shown in various ways and evaluates to $2\zeta(3)$. If you look around, I am sure it has already been done on the site.

Contours is a fun way to evaluate many Euler sums. A method published by Flajolet and Salvy in their paper "Euler sums and contour integral representations".
Use the 'kernel' $\frac{1}{2}\pi\cot(\pi z)(\psi(-z))$ and note the residues for the pole at 0, the positive integers, n, and the negative integers, -n.

The pole at the negative integers is simple and the residue is

$$Res(-n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{2n^{2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^{3}}$$

The residue at the positive integers is order 2 and is:

$$Res(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{2n^{2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}}$$

The residue at the pole at 0 is $$\frac{-1}{2}\zeta(3)$$

summing these and setting to 0 gives:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{2n^{2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^{3}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{2n^{2}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}}-1/2\zeta(3)=0$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{n^{2}}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}}=0$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{n^{2}}=2\zeta(3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx \overset{IBP} =-\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{ \ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx \\
& = \frac14 \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x} \left(2{\ln^2(1-x) }-{\ln^2(1-x^2)}-{\ln^2\frac{1-x}{1+x} } \right)
\end{align}
Substitute ${t=1-x}$, ${t=1-x^2}$ and $ t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ in the three integrals, respectively

\begin{align}
I & = \frac38\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t}dt
 - \frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t^2}dt\\ &=\frac38\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t}dt
 - \frac12\int_0^1 {\ln^2t}\left( \frac1{1-t}-\frac t{1-t^2}\right)dt
\end{align}
Let $t\to t^2$ in the last integral

\begin{align}
I & =- \frac1{16} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t}dt
\overset{IBP} = -\frac1{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1-t)}{t}dt\\
& =  -\frac1{8} \int_0^1 \ln t \>d\left( \int_0^t\frac{\ln (1-u)}u du\right)
 =  -\frac1{8} \int_0^1 \frac{-\int_0^t\frac{\ln (1-u)}u du}{t} dt \\
&=-\frac1{8} \int_0^1 \frac{Li_2(t)}{t} dt =    -\frac1{8}Li_3(1) = -\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of writing $$\frac{\log (x) \log (x+1)}{x+1}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_n x^n \log (x)$$ by a Taylor expansion looks good to me almost when you take into account that, for value of $n$ greater or equal to $0$, $$
\int_0^1 x^n \ln x dx=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}
$$ So $$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \cdot \ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{a_n}{(n+1)^2}
$$ But, at this point, I am stuck with the $a_n$ and then with the summation. I made some numerical evaluations and observed that the convergence is not very fast.

I shall wait for answers to learn more.

Thanks for the interesting problem.

Comment: $a_n$ is proportional to $H_n$ where $H_n$ is the harmonic number.  I am still working on proving this.  Not sure why, but I observe that $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{(n+1)^2}=\zeta(3)
$$
Thanks!! let me know

Comment: @Jeff. The $a_n$ are $(-1)^{n-1} H_n$ !! So, it works.

Comment: yes except I am looking for a proof that doesn't rely on knowing the answer.  Thanks still!

Comment: @Jeff&Claude This is indeed a very interesting question. I did the same computations as Claude and got stuck at the same point. Why is it so that $\sum_1^\infty \frac{H_n}{(n+1)^2}=\zeta(3)$??

Comment: @Etienne Yes, I am not sure why...If we can prove that, we are done!