# How to evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{\tanh ^{-1}(x)\log(x)}{(1-x) x (x+1)} \operatorname d \!x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

How to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_0^1\frac{\tanh ^{-1}(x)\log(x)}{(1-x) x (x+1)} \operatorname d \!x $$

The numerical result is $= -1.38104$ and when I look at it, I have no idea how to work on it. Could you provide me hits to evaluate the integral above?

Thank you.

Comment: Analytically.  Apply Simpson's Rule, or similar.

Comment: the value on the picture is from wolfram alpha

Comment: There is no closed form for the antiderivative. Numerical methods seem to be the way.

Comment: [Numerical evaluation to 10000 digits](http://pastebin.com/2fGUk9jX)

Comment: Not that it matters, but $$I~=~\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{\text{arctanh }x}{1-x^2}\cdot\dfrac{\ln x}xdx~=~\dfrac14\int_0^1\Big(\text{arctanh }^2x\Big)'\cdot\Big(\ln^2x\Big)'dx$$ since $$\quad\text{arctanh }'x=\dfrac1{1-x^2}\quad\text{and}\quad\ln'x=\dfrac1x$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your integral can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{{\rm artanh}\ {x}\ln{x}}{x(1-x)(1+x)}{\rm d}x
=\int^1_0\frac{{\rm artanh}\ {x}\ln{x}}{x}{\rm d}x+\int^1_0\frac{x{\rm artanh}\ {x}\ln{x}}{1-x^2}{\rm d}x
\end{align}
The first integral is
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{{\rm artanh}\ {x}\ln{x}}{x}{\rm d}x
=&\chi_2(x)\ln{x}\Bigg{|}^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{\chi_2(x)}{x}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\chi_3(1)=-\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)
\end{align}
The second integral is
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{x{\rm artanh}\ {x}\ln{x}}{1-x^2}{\rm d}x
=&\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{1}{2k+1}\int^1_0 x^{2n+2}\ln{x}\ {\rm d}x\\
=&\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}H_n-H_{2n+1}}{(2n+3)^2}\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^2}-\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}
\end{align}
For the first sum, consider $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{\left(\gamma+\psi_0(-z)\right)^2}{(2z+1)^2}$. At the positive integers,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,n)
=&\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\left[\frac{1}{(2z+1)^2(z-n)^2}+\frac{2H_n}{(2z+1)^2(z-n)}\right]\\
=&2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^2}-\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)+4
\end{align}
At $z=0$,
\begin{align}
{\rm Res}(f,0)=\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac{1}{z^2(2z+1)^2}=-4
\end{align}
At $z=-\frac{1}{2}$,
\begin{align}
{\rm Res}\left(f,-\tfrac12\right)=\frac{1}{4}\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}z}(\gamma+\psi_0(-z))^2\Bigg{|}_{z=-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\ln{2}
\end{align}
Since the sum of residues is zero,
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln{2}$$
For the second sum, consider $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)(\gamma+\psi_0(-2z))}{(2z+1)^2}$. Note that the poles at the half integers are cancelled by the zeroes of $\pi\cot(\pi z)$. At the positive integers,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,n)
=&\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\left[\frac{1}{2(2z+1)^2(z-n)^2}+\frac{H_{2n}}{(2z+1)^2(z-n)}\right]\\
=&\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}-\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)+2
\end{align}
At the negative integers,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,-n)
=&\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}+1\\
=&\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)
\end{align}
At $z=0$,
\begin{align}
{\rm Res}(f,0)=-2
\end{align}
Since the sum of residues is zero,
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)$$
Hence, if I had not made any mistakes, the original integral is simply
$$\int^1_0\frac{\operatorname{artanh}{x}\ln{x}}{x(1-x)(1+x)}{\rm d}x=-\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln{2}$$

Comment: Isn't it $\operatorname{arctanh}$ instead of $\operatorname{artanh}$

Comment: @Darksonn Both notations are accepted if I am not wrong.

Comment: I'm learning something new everyday from your posts, +1 of course. One question: is it possible to solve 2nd integral without residue approach?

Comment: Your result seems to be correct, I've confirmed it to 1000 digits

Comment: @Venus Thank you for your kind compliment. For the second integral, it is possible to solve it without residues. For example, one can convert the sums into integrals that are in fact mixed partial derivatives of the beta function. However, I find this route too much of a hassle, and prefer to use the method of residues which is more efficient instead.

Comment: @Darksonn Thank you for your confirmation. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is a pure beauty ! Thanks for your nice work. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comments, it seems that there is no explicit antiderivative. Even numerical methods could be problematic because the integrand is undefined at the bounds.

One possible way is to perform a Taylor expansion around $x=0$. We so can get $$\frac{\tanh ^{-1}(x)}{(1-x) x (x+1)}=1+\frac{4 x^2}{3}+\frac{23 x^4}{15}+\frac{176 x^6}{105}+\frac{563
   x^8}{315}+\frac{6508 x^{10}}{3465}+\frac{88069 x^{12}}{45045}+O\left(x^{13}\right)$$ and we are left with a series of integrals $$I_n=\int x^{2n}\log(x)dx=\frac{x^{2 n+1} ((2 n+1) \log (x)-1)}{(2 n+1)^2}$$ So $$J_n=\int_0^1 x^{2n}\log(x)dx=-\frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2}$$ Using the above expansion, the result of the integral is $$A_{12}=-\frac{118164390159964}{91398648466125}\approx -1.29285$$ Adding more terms in the expansion, we have $$A_{14}=-\frac{118985678275612}{91398648466125} \approx -1.30183$$ $$A_{16}=-\frac{587809463058901481}{449041559914072125}\approx -1.30903$$ $$A_{18}=-\frac{4049985594549210440279}{3079976059450620705375}\approx -1.31494$$ Now, I am tired with fractions !! This will converge but not very fast (because the coefficients of the Taylor expansion constantly increase).

If we use the previous results and report them on a graph, it looks that we can approximate more or less $$A_{2n}\approx\frac{a+b n}{1+c n}=-\frac{1.01437+0.827943 n}{1+0.604336 n}$$ for which the limit should be $-1.37000$.

Making the model slightly more complex $$A_{2n}\approx\frac{a+b n^d}{1+c n^d}=-\frac{0.98352+0.984458 n^{0.903476}}{1+0.714051 n^{0.903476}}$$ leads to a limit equal to $-1.37869$.

Comment: I think such *closed-form* exist since the denominator of the integrand can be decomposed as $$\frac{1}{(1-x)x(1+x)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2(x-1)}$$and seeing [this OP](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/927427/146687) (although, it's not the same), I am quite sure it does exist but it's just my feeling & I could certainly be wrong :-)

Comment: @Venus A closed form indeed exists. In fact, this integral is alot simpler than the one in the link you provided.

Comment: @M.N.C.E. Really?? You must have the answer, I presume?

Comment: @Venus. I thought the same as you but I did not find any way to compute any of the integrals. Cheers :-)

Comment: @M.N.C.E.Could you provide some answer ? I am very curious. Thanks. Cheers :-)

Comment: I am working on an answer and will upload it shortly. Thanks.