# How to evaluate these two euler sums?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

How to evaluate 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^52^n}~~,~~\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^62^n}$$
In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972775/what-is-a-closed-form-for-large-int-01-frac-ln31x-ln2xxdx?lq=1) M gives a closed form for the first series,but it contains a zeta function,can it be simplified any more? And is there a closed form for the second series.