# Interesting Logarithmic Integral: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2(1+x)}{x} \;dx $

Tags: integration

Other than numerical approximation, how can we calculate the closed form of this integral?

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2(1+x)}{x} \;dx $$

Comment: Here is the value to 30 decimal places for those that are interested:

    0.195745588199876253442970994564.

Comment: There's no way ? :/ I have decomposed into a series then stuck on them.

Comment: I believe a closed form exists ... Have you tried expanding $\ln^2(1+x)$ in Taylor and then get into Euler sums?

Comment: I think it can be done via a parametric differentiation technique but.. at the end of the day, it'll still be a solution in terms of special functions (i.e. an integral or series).

Comment: @Tolaso , Yep and a sum $ \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{H_k (-1)^{k-1}}{k^3} $ , is disturbing me

Comment: @CameronWilliams What kind of Parametrisation ? To compute the derivate of a self-defined function ?

Comment: $$I=2 \zeta(2) \,\zeta(3)- \frac{29}{8} \zeta(5).$$ Source: [this post.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972775/what-is-a-closed-form-for-large-int-01-frac-ln31x-ln2xxdx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @nospoon , Thanks ! . But I see that only the result is supplied there . I can't find the proof :/

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908108/how-to-find-large-int-01-frac-ln31x-ln-xx-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK as I suggested in a comment here is an approach.Let us begin with the Taylor series of $\ln^2(1+x)$. It is known to be:

$$\ln^2 (1+x) = 2 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_{n-1}}{n} x^n$$

Then we have successively:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2 (1+x)}{x} \, {\rm d}x &= 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2 x}{x} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_{n-1}}{n} x^n \, {\rm d}x \\ 
 &=2 \int_{0}^{1} \ln^2 x \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_{n-1}}{n} x^{n-1} \, {\rm d}x\\ 
 &= 2 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_{n-1}}{n} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \ln^2 x \, {\rm d}x\\ 
 &= 2 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_{n-1}}{n^4}\\ 
 &=2 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \left [ \mathcal{H}_n - \frac{1}{n} \right ]}{n^4} \\ 
 &= 2 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_n}{n^4} - 2 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^5} \\
 &= 2 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_n}{n^4} - 2 - \frac{15 \zeta(5)}{16}
\end{align*}

Well for the Euler sum first of all we have the generating function:

\begin{align} 
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^3}z^n 
=&2{\rm Li}_4(z)+{\rm Li}_4\left(\tfrac{z}{z-1}\right)-{\rm Li}_4(1-z)-{\rm Li}_3(z)\ln(1-z)-\frac{1}{2}{\rm Li}_2^2\left(\tfrac{z}{z-1}\right)\\ 
&+\frac{1}{2}{\rm Li}_2(z)\ln^2(1-z)+\frac{1}{2}{\rm Li}_2^2(z)+\frac{1}{6}\ln^4(1-z)-\frac{1}{6}\ln{z}\ln^3(1-z)\\ 
&+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln^2(1-z)+\zeta(3)\ln(1-z)+\frac{\pi^4}{90} 
\end{align}

Integrating once and plugging $z=-1$ we get the value of the sum. I am not presenting the full calculatios but it suffices to say that:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_n}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^2 \zeta(3)}{4} -\frac{43 \zeta(5)}{32}+1$$

Thus:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2 (1+x)}{x} \, {\rm d}x = \frac{\pi^2 \zeta(3)}{3} - \frac{29 \zeta(5)}{8}$$

Comment: (+1) Yes exactly, Thanks ! I was stuck at the generating function of third order there. Now I've got it

Comment: @AdityaNarayanSharma As for your alternating Euler sum, here is the result:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n \mathcal{H}_n}{n^3}=2{\rm Li}_4 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{11\pi^4}{360}+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)\ln{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln^2{2}+\frac{1}{12}\ln^4{2} $$