# Books about harmonic numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, reference-request, book-recommendation, harmonic-numbers

I'm looking for books about [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), where I could find proofs of results about them. For example a [proof](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic266.html) for the fact, that the generating function of the [generalized harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  H_{n}^{(m)} z^n = \frac {\mathrm{Li}_m(z)}{1-z}.
$$
I'm also interested in particular evaluations of sums involving harmonic numbers, like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/604316/153012):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2 2^n}=\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)\zeta(2).
$$
I'm also interested in sums of generalized harmonic numbers and also alternating harmonic numbers.

Comment: Have a look at this - Not really a book, but a [MathWorld@Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) on harmonic numbers.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Thank you, I've seen this, but the article is not so good. There are a lot of evaluation marked as "pers. comm.", and there is no reference of the proofs.

Comment: You might be interested in the Harmonic Series Facebook group (see https://www.facebook.com/groups/178723409566339/about) which contains a considerable number of related sums and integrals.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in [Multiple Zeta Functions, Multiple Polylogarithms and Their Special Values](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9634), by Jianqiang Zhao.

Answer (score 3):

[Zeta and q-Zeta Functions and Associated Series and Integrals (Elsevier Insights)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123852188) and the papers referenced therein regarding harmonic numbers and generalised harmonic numbers has a fair bit of info.

Answer (score 3):

For a multitude of problems on infinite sums involving the harmonic and generalised harmonic numbers, so-called *Euler sums*, you cannot go pass Cornel Ioan Valean's latest book: [(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/303002461X).

Solutions to all problems are given and some of the sums are very challenging indeed. It is an absolute must have book if you are seriously interested in such things.

**Update**

You may also consider having a look at Ali Shadhar Olaikhan's book [An Introduction To The Harmonic Series And Logarithmic Integrals: For High School Students Up To Researchers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1736736000).