# Generating function for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, power-series, generating-functions, closed-form

I would like to get the closed form for this generating function, assuming the $k$ is given up front / held constant: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k x^n$

However I don't know if this is too advanced for me or if I am in over my head because I can't seem to get anywhere with this. One thing I did find, playing around with derivatives, is that if:

$F_0(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$

$F_1(x) = xF'_0(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n}$

$F_2(x) = xF'_1(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n}$

$F_3(x) = xF'_2(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3 x^{n}$

$F_k(x) = xF'_{k-1}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k x^{n}$ and this is what I want to compute the closed form for

Does a closed form exist for this or do I have to compute this in $O(k)$ time by going through each level, computing the derivative, multiplying by $x$, and so on?

Comment: See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394168/evaluate-the-sum-sum-i-0-infty-frac-in-4i/394207#394207)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A closed form does exist. One has
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^px^n=\frac1{1-x}\:\omega_p\left(\frac{x}{1-x} \right), \quad |x|<1, 
$$
with the polynomials $$
\omega_n\left(x \right)=\sum_{k=0}^n \begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix}k!x^k 
$$ where $\displaystyle \begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix}$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

A proof can be found in [Boyadzhiev's paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/2005/233849.pdf). A related formula: [eulerian polynomials](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials#Three_identities).

Comment: I am guessing this is not something I can realistically expect to derive on my own? I am not understanding much of this paper. Is there no easier derivation?

Comment: @KaliMa I'm afraid it won't be much simpler.

Comment: So is my derivative relationship more complex than this / is it a wasted observation? I don't see that in the paper anywhere

Comment: @KaliMa: You might find this step-by-step [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801457/closed-form-for-1k-nk-generalized-harmonic-number/1802085#1802085) helpful.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer That answer is great, but my difficulty lies in finding some way to handle $(zD_z)^k$ (such as in the example in my post where I have to go through each level). For example deriving some closed form or summation for applying $(zD_z)^k$ to $\frac{1}{1-z}$. Let's say $k=30$. Would you manually derivate $\frac{1}{1-z}$ that many times or is there a better way?

Comment: @KaliMa Observe that, by using the formula I gave in my answer above, we just get $$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{30}x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{30} \begin{Bmatrix}30\\k\end{Bmatrix}\frac{k!\:x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}. 
$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa I don't understand why the formula works, though, or how it can be derived. I don't understand that paper (it's too dense for me and I have no idea where I need to be looking)

Comment: @KaliMa I understand what you mean. Sometimes one has to accept to take time to really understand what's going on in a mathematical subject. I think time might be very often our friend.

Comment: Is this Stirling equation related to Faulhaber's formula in any way?

Comment: The answer is yes, by a Cauchy product. One may use that $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n \cdot \sum_{n\ge 0} x^n= \sum_{n\ge 0} (\sum_{0\le k \le n} a_k) x^n$. Applied to $a_n=n^p$.

Comment: @KaliMa: I think that Olivier Oloas answer provides a nice manageable solution. Note that the operator $zD_z$ and the Stirling numbers are *[intimately connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DifferentialOperator.html)*.

Comment: I am sure it is manageable to someone who is already familiar with much of this, but to me it looks like it has a ton of superfluous information that is really distracting for me; I need something a little more focused on this specific question