# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac1{1-\cos (x^2)}\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty} n^5x^n$

Tags: calculus, limits, power-series

I'm trying to solve this limit but I'm not sure how to do it.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac1{1-\cos(x^2)}\sum_{n=4}^{\infty} n^5x^n$$
I thought of finding the function that represents the sum but I had a hard time finding it.
I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Here is a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242878/finding-sum-of-a-series-difference-of-cubes/242996#242996) to sum the series.

Comment: @Cortizol This edit was inappropriate - you changed the formula entirely.  It is better in this sort of case to ask the OP for clarification, and ask them to edit their question themselves.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Look at picture: $\cos x^2$, not $\cos^2 x$. So I edited.

Comment: Is it $\cos(x^2)$ or $\cos^2(x)$?

Comment: @Cortizol Ah, my apologies.  I hadn't seen the post while the picture was still a part of it.  I reverted.

Comment: @Cortizol: *wrong*!  You see a contradiction - you ask the OP for clarification.  Do *not* change the meaning/intent/content of a question, even if it is clear to you what it should be.

Comment: @RonGordon On the picture it was $\cos x^2$ (without brackets), then Gigili changed picture into TeX but with $\cos^2 x$, so I edited into $\cos x^2$. If some moderators can see full edit history that would be great.

Comment: When Shookie comes back tomorrow, she can tell us what was really intended...

Comment: @Cortizol: Shookie is the OP and is the one asking the question.  By changing the content, you rendered my answer completely wrong.  Perhaps I should have noticed the contradiction, but I typically answer the question posed.  As an editor, it is OK for you to clean up the typography or fix typos, but please do not change content to the point where it can render someone's answer incorrect.

Comment: @RonGordon You don't get it. But we will see what OP is going to say. Until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**:

As $x\to0, |x|<1\implies \sum_{0\le n<\infty}x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ ([Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence))

Differentiating wrt $x,$  $$\sum_{0\le n<\infty} nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}\implies \sum_{0\le n<\infty} nx^n=\frac x{(1-x)^2}$$

Again differentiating wrt $x$  $$\sum_{0\le n<\infty}n^2x^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}+\frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}\implies  \sum_{0\le n<\infty}n^2x^n=\frac x{(1-x)^2}+\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}$$

Can you continue the process to  find $\sum_{0\le n<\infty}n^5x^n ,$ hence $\sum_{4\le n<\infty}n^5x^n ?$

Answer (score 2):

Of course finding a formula for the sum of the series is not needed to solve this.
$$\begin{align}
\cos(x^2) &= 1 - \frac{x^4}{2} + O(x^8)\qquad\text{as }x \to 0
\\
\frac{1}{1-\cos(x^2)} &= 2 x^{-4} + O(1)
\\
\sum_{n=4}^\infty n^5 x^n &= 4^5 x^4 + O(x^5)
\\
\frac{1}{1-\cos(x^2)}\sum_{n=4}^\infty n^5 x^n &= 2\cdot 4^5 + O(x)
\end{align}$$
and the limit is $2\cdot 4^5 = 2048$.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to sum the series to determine the limit.  As $x \to 0$, the sum $\sim 4^5 x^4$, while the denominator $= \sin^2{x} \sim x^2$ as $x \to 0$.  Thus, the ratio $\sim 4^5 x^2$ as $x \to 0$, so the limit is $0$.

**EDIT**

An editor inappropriately changed the question after I posted this.  The denominator is $1-\cos{x^2} \sim (x^2)^2/2$, so the limit is then $2 \cdot 4^5$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first term is $$\frac 1 {1-(1-x^4/2+O(x^8))} = \frac 2 {x^4}(1+O(x^4))$$ and that the second term is $$4^5 x^4(1+O(x))$$
(The question keeps changing; this is for the $$\cos x^2$$ denominator.)

Answer (score 0):

If you evaluate the series, you get

$$ -{\frac {{x}^{4} \left( 243\,{x}^{5}-1426\,{x}^{4}+3454\,{x}^{3}-4386
\,{x}^{2}+3019\,x-1024 \right) }{ \left( x-1 \right) ^{6} \left( 1-
\cos \left( {x}^{2} \right)  \right) }}
 $$

$$ \sim \frac{1024x^4}{1-(1-\frac{x^4}{2!}+\dots)}\sim \frac{1024 x^4}{x^4/2!}=2048. $$