# Power series $\sum n^3a_nz^n$

Tags: power-series

> If $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$, what is $\sum n^3a_nz^n$?

The desired sum is $a_1z+8a_2z^2+27a_3z^3+\cdots$. I can't see how to write the desired sum in terms of $f$. For example, I could substitute $kz$ for $z$ to get $f(kz)=\sum k^na_nz^n$, but that doesn't help me get the coefficient $n^3$.

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242878/finding-sum-of-a-series-difference-of-cubes/242996#242996).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Differentiate, multiply by $z$, differentiate, $\dots$.

Comment: I see, thanks! The answer should be $z^3f'''(z)+3z^2f''(z)+zf'(z)$, if my calculation is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's the right answer. If $r$ is the radius of convergence of the original series, the expression is only valid for $z|\lt r$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$, then $zf'(z) = \sum n a_n z^n$. Applying this thrice you would get-

$\sum n^3 a_n z^n = z \left(f'(z) + 3z f''(z) + z^2 f'''(z)\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Find the coordinates $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$) of $x^3$ in the basis $(1,x,x(x-1),x(x-1)(x-2))$ of $\mathbb R_3[x]$
so 
$$\sum n^3a_n z^n=\alpha_0f(z)+\alpha_1 z f'(z)+\alpha_2 z^2 f''(z)+\alpha_3z^3f'''(z)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$z(a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \ldots)' = a_1 z + 2 a_2 z^2 + \ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

For the general case,
you will encounter the
Stirling numbers
of the second kind.

In this case,
you are given
$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$
and want to find
$f_k(z)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^ka_nz^n
$.

By repeated differentiation,
$f^{(k)}(z)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} (n)_k a_nz^{n-k}$
where
$(n)_k
=n(n-1)...(n-k+1)
$
is the Pochhammer symbol
denoting the falling factorial.

Therefore
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n)_k a_nz^{n}
=z^kf^{(k)}(z)
$.

We now use the definition
of the Stirling numbers
of the second kind:
$\sum_{j=0}^k S(k, j) (n)_j
=n^k
$.

Note: The Stirling numbers of the first kind
go the other way,
expressing
$(n)_k 
=\sum_{j=0}^k s(k, j) n^j
$

These make is easy to get a formula
for $f_k(z)$:

$\begin{align}
f_k(z)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^ka_nz^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n\sum_{j=0}^k S(k, j) (n)_j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n S(k, j) (n)_j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k S(k, j) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n  (n)_j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k S(k, j) z^k f^{(k)}(z)\\
\end{align}
$

For $k=3$,
$S(3, 1..3) = [1, 3, 1]$,
so
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3a_nz^n
=z^3 f'''(z)+3z^2f''(z)+zf'(z)
$.

For $k=4$,
$S(4, 1..4) = [1, 7, 6, 1]$,
so
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^4a_nz^n
=z^4 f^{(4)}(z)+7z^3 f'''(z)+6z^2f''(z)+zf'(z)
$.