# Sum of infinite series with an unknown

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

How do I calculate the infinite sum of this series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2q^n = -\frac{q(q+1)}{(q-1)^3}\ \text{when}\ |q| < 1.$$

How does wolfram alpha get this result?

Comment: Which one of the above results do you mean?

Comment: Apparently, there was some unfortunate editing here.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427etrd0bedh67

Comment: Did you mean [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+n^2+*+q^n)?

Comment: @user3071205: But this link is not the same as you added in the body. :-)

Comment: Does my edit ask the question you wanted to ask?

Comment: yes. I added the correct link in the original post.

Comment: If $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k$, then $z\frac{df(z)}{dz} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k a_k z^k$. Since we know what $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k$ is.....

Comment: I rolled back the edit because it is better to have the formula here than to have a link to another site which displays it.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2q^n=q\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2q^{n-1}=q\cdot\frac{\text d}{\text dq}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty nq^n\right) $$
It is well-known that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$ (given $|x|<1$), so we have \begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2q^n&=q\cdot\frac{\text d}{\text dq}\left(\frac q{(1-q)^2}\right)\\
&=q\cdot\frac{(1-q)^2+2q(1-q)}{(1-q)^4}\\
&=\frac{q(1+q)}{(1-q)^3} \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242878/finding-sum-of-a-series-difference-of-cubes/242996#242996). Recalling the series

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} q^k = \frac{q}{1-q} $$

Now, apply the operator $(qD)^2   = (qD)(qD)    $ where $D= \frac{d}{dq} $ to both sides of the above equation.